# Write a python 3 procedure to list a table

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python 3 procedure to list a table.

The following code works:

```
row_names = ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014']
row_names = ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014']
Q1 = [92186686.0, 105377495.0, 105614831.0, 132754996.0, 148215172.0]
Q2 = [104962317.0, 110508367.0, 128186331.0, 155886320.0, 183020484.0]
Q3 = [112246699.0, 106483616.0, 141499253.0, 162577034.0, 209049734.0]
Q4 = [110142209.0, 104711167.0, 131444819.0, 145805847.0, 222521075.0]

column_data = [Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4]

column_names = ['Years', "Q1", 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4'] 

data = [column_names] + list(zip(row_names, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4))
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    line = ' '.join(str(x).ljust(16) for x in d)
    print(line)
    if i == 0:
        print('-' * len(line))
```

But when I change it to a function with the code below:

```
def table(row_names, column_names, column_data):
    data = [column_names] + list(zip(row_names, column_data))
    #data = [titles] + list(zip(years, column_data))
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        line = ' '.join(str(x).ljust(16) for x in d)
        print(line)
        if i == 0:
            print('-' * len(line))
    return
```

The column data is listed horizontally, instead of vertically. Please help me understand where have gone wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you calling this function?

Comment: Try `data = [column_names] + list(zip(row_names, *coloum_data))`

Comment: Given that the only thing that's changed is the line where you `zip` things, I would guess that you're either calling this function differently, or the `zip` is acting differently to what you're expecting now that you're zipping 2 lists, rather than 5

Comment: Yeah....what @D.LaRocque said...but I wanted to walk you down the thought process of what might have changed

Comment: Have you considered using the Pandas library to work with tabular data?

Answer (score 1):

As @D.LaRocque pointed out in the comments, the problem is probably this line:

```
data = [column_names] + list(zip(row_names, column_data))
```

which you need to change to this:

```
data = [column_names] + list(zip(row_names, *column_data))
```

The `zip()` function acts differently depending on how many arguments it's given. Keep in mind `column_data` is a list of lists - `[Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4]`. By default, `zip()` is going to take that outer list and zip it to `row_names`, such that `row_names[0]` corresponds to `Q1`, `row_names[1]` corresponds to `Q2`, etc.

What you want instead is for `row_names[0]` to correspond with `Q1[0]`, `Q2[0]`, etc. To achieve this, you need to pass those as separate arguments to the `zip()` function. That's what the `*` operator does above - it unpacks the list `[Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4]` into positional arguments `Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4`.

Answer (score 0):

You changed how you call `zip`, from zip with 5 lists(namely `row_names`, `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3` and `Q4`) to two lists (`row_names` and `column_data`).

Since `column_data` is a list containing `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3` and `Q4`, we would like to unpack `column_data` so that `zip` sees it as 4 different lists.

In order to do this, we use the star operator, so that

```py
a, b, c = *[a, b, c]
```

Therefore, the corrected function is the following

```py
def table(row_names, column_names, column_data):
    data = [column_names] + list(zip(row_names, *column_data))
    #data = [titles] + list(zip(years, column_data))
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        line = ' '.join(str(x).ljust(16) for x in d)
        print(line)
        if i == 0:
            print('-' * len(line))
        return
```